# Get the value of a macro using a string with macro name

Tags: c, macros

I have a set of macro definitions that the name only change on the number between "C_" and "_E". What I need is a macro that gets a integer variable and returns the integer value of the corresponding macro definition in case it exists, if it does not exist, it returns "-1" or gives a compile error. Is that possible? The code I need is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define C_1_E 4
#define C_2_E 2
#define C_3_E 0
#define C_4_E 420

#define STR(x) #x
#define STR_MACRO(x) "C_" STR(x) "_E"

#define MACRO_VAL(x) ... // return the value of the macro C_x_E when x=1,2,3 or 4

void main() {
  uint8_t n;
  for(n=1;n<=4;n++) printf("val %u: %u\n",n, MACRO_VAL(STR_MACRO(n)));
}
```

Expected output:

```
val 1: 4
val 2: 2
val 3: 0
val 4: 420
```

According to my search, this is not possible, but I can swear I did cross this solution once, but I didn't need it back then although I thought it could be helpful.

Comment: Macro replacement cannot replace variables with their values, nor can `#if` or `#elif` directives evaluate variables to their values, so there is no way to do this using only preprocessor features. With constants instead of values, as in `MACRO_VAL(2)` instead of `MACRO_VAL(n)`, the macro `MACRO_VAL` can be defined to be replaced with `C_2_E`, and so on. Or, if the number of values is known and reasonably limited, you can construct an array and look up values at run-time.

Comment: This is a crystal clear case for a look-up table. You shouldn't even be using macros, use enums.

Comment: There would be a solution if you would call the macro with literal numbers, e.g. `MACRO_VAL(1)`, so you could unroll the loop in your source code and maybe use another macro that is called like `PRINT_VAL(1)` to create the corresponding `printf` with a call to `MACRO_VAL`.

Comment: Not possible, at least not without boost.preprocessor (in which case you'd have to replace your whole loop with a macro "loop" that duplicates the body N times).

Comment: You say you want a function, but the example code seems to be asking for a macro.  Which is it?  You say you have a string with the macro name, but you seem instead to have a variable containing a number that appears in the macro name.  Which is it?

Comment: The example macros all expand to integer constants.  Can this be taken as a constraint on which a solution may rely?

Comment: You write that you want the value of the macro "in case it exists".  What is supposed to happen if the macro *does not* exist?  Would it be acceptable for that to produce a compile error?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I did edit my question to clarify everything you asked.

Comment: @RuiCunha, thank you.  If a function is not acceptable, as your update seems to clarify, then I take that to mean that you require the preprocessor to perform the evaluation at compile time, as opposed to the value being determined at runtime.  As others have written, this is not possible, for variables do not exist or have values at compile time.  But are you sure you really need compile-time evaluation?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, No, I can use a function and do a string compare of the macros or create a constant array instead of individual macros and use an iteration variable, but this specific case would be much better if I could just get a macro value using a string with the macro name, so I don't have to hardcode an ugly big block of code to do the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have a macro specifically, not a function, then it must be that a macro that expands to a function call is not acceptable either.  That makes sense to me only if you need the conversion of macro number to macro expansion to be performed at compile time, by the preprocessor.  That doesn't appear to be a necessity for the example code, but there are cases where it would indeed be needed.

And that's too bad, because the C preprocessor then provides no way to achieve what you ask.  Variables do not exist or have values at compile time, so there is no way at compile time for the compiler to convert a variable name to the value it represents, much less to build a macro name out of it, much less to expand such a name to its replacement text.

You could, however, do it with numeric literals instead of a variable:

```
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define MACRO_VAL(n) EXPAND(C_ ## n ## _E)

printf("val %d: %d\n",n, 1, MACRO_VAL(1));
printf("val %d: %d\n",n, 2, MACRO_VAL(2));
printf("val %d: %d\n",n, 3, MACRO_VAL(3));
printf("val %d: %d\n",n, 4, MACRO_VAL(4));
```

If you try to expand that with an argument that does not produce the name of a defined macro or in-scope variable then that (almost surely) will produce a compile-time error for a reference to an undefined variable.

---

If run-time evaluation were acceptable after all, then you could write a function that does it (which you could wrap in a macro if you wanted):

```
#define MACRO_VAL(n) lookup_macro(n)

#define EXPAND(x) x
#define MACRO_CASE(i) case i: return EXPAND(C_ ## i ## _E)
int lookup_macro(int n) {
    switch (n) {
       MACRO_CASE(1);
       MACRO_CASE(2);
       MACRO_CASE(3);
       MACRO_CASE(4);
       default: return -1;
    }
}
```

That will return -1 for an arithmetic argument that is not covered by the defined cases.

You could also consider a lookup table, possibly wrapped in a function, but that would require somewhat more code to provide a -1 result in the event of an argument that doesn't match any macro, especially if the macro numbers are not all consecutive or if the least of them is not known in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes total sense to me.
I like your lookup_macro solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Token pasting approaches are inappropriate as `x` is a variable name.

Here is a simplistic approach that will work as long as the macro argument is an expression without side effects:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define C_1_E 4
#define C_2_E 2
#define C_3_E 0
#define C_4_E 420

// return the value of the macro C_x_E when x=1,2,3 or 4
#define MACRO_VAL(x)  ((x) == 1 ? C_1_E : \
                       (x) == 2 ? C_2_E : \
                       (x) == 3 ? C_3_E : \
                       (x) == 4 ? C_4_E : -1)

int main() {
    int n;
    for (n = 1; n <= 4; n++)
        printf("val %u: %u\n", n, MACRO_VAL(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your alternative solution to my problem is very simple and will work great in my case.